# Regex with dir command directly into the powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to list all the files with .rar or .zip file type.

I tried regular expressions like the ones you can find in the online regex helpers, but none of those seems to work.

Maybe the problem is trying to do this directly into the cmd/powershell instead of a script ?

```bsh
dir *./(zip|rar)/
```

The expected result would be something like:
file1.rar
file2.rar
file3.zip

Comment: Have you looked into using [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6) command?

Comment: My idea was to just use one line, like you would do in the unix shell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Powershell, `dir` is an alias for `Get-ChildItem`. You cannot use a regex directly. Powershell is interpretting your regex as a wildcard.

As noted in the other answers and in [the Get-ChildItem documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6), you can to use a comma to separate your search terms. `dir *.zip,*.rar`, which is an alias for

```
Get-ChildItem -path *.zip,*.rar
```

If you'd like to use a regex, you need to assign the result of `Get-ChildItem` to a variable and then use `-match`.

```
> $dir = Get-ChildItem
> $dir -match "\.(zip|rar)$"
```

Or use parentheses to turn it into a one-liner:

```
(Get-ChildItem) -match "\.(zip|rar)$"
```

Comment: Thanks for updating. Good point that a regex was explicitly asked for (and while not strictly needed here, other cases may require a regex). Yes, `-match` matches any substring, unlike the wildcard-based `-like` / argument-based wildcard matching, where the entire input string must match. As an aside: In PowerShell _Core_ `Get-ChildItem` output now stringifies to _full paths_, so it's safer to do `(Get-ChildItem).Name` in order to limit matching to mere file _names_, but then you get just names as output too. `(Get-ChildItem).Where({ $_.Name -match '\.(zip|rar)$' })` preserves the output type.

Comment: @mklement0 nice! Great tips!

Answer (score 2):

get-childitem -path takes an array.  Not regex, but an array of wildcards that serve the same purpose.

```
dir *.zip,*.rar
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (not using regex though):

`Get-ChildItem -Path "Path\*" -Include *.rar,*zip`

Answer (score 0):

```
dir ("*.zip","*.rar")
```

should do the trick...